# How to reset this string scanning code for a new letter?

Tags: c, loops

I'm in the middle of homework and nearly finish. This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
    char word[100],*ptr,input;
    int count,i,n;
    printf("Enter the word : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", word);
    ptr = &word;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter the letter : ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        if(input == '-'){
                printf("Exit.");
                return 0;
        }
        for(i=0;word[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
            if(*ptr == input)
                count++;
            ptr++;
        }
        printf("Has %d of '%c'",count,input);
        printf("\n");
    }while(input != '-')
}
```

This code will extract the number of letter in string

For example : If you input "WWWWooo" it will give you "has 4 of 'W'" and "has 3 of 'o'"

Code will exit when you put '-' letter.

Problem that I find is the 'count' value seems to remain the total of number of the first letter I want to find.

What I expect : "WWWWooo" will give "has 4 of 'W'" and "has 3 of 'o'"

What I get is "has 4 of 'W'" and "has 4 of 'o'". The count value didn't reset.

I tried to put `count = 0;` on the top of do while loop and the output will always be 0 for the second letter scanned for.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Put count = 0 at the end, after the printf

Comment: It's not only `count` that has to be reset, but `ptr` too. But you can get rid of `ptr` anyway. Replace `*ptr == input` by `word[i] == input`. That makes much more sense because you use the same varialbe in the `for` condition and in the body

Comment: Please double check that you have shown a [mre]. The shown code a) does not compile b) with an obvious fix, does not behave as described.

Comment: @Fabiobreo I tried that and it return 0 everytime

Comment: You need to do both comment proposals, Fabios and Ingos. (And fix some other issues....) Then I get `Enter the word : Enter the letter : Has 4 of 'W'
Enter the letter : Has 3 of 'w'
Enter the letter : Exit.` e.g. here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php Please learn to read and fix compiler warnings too, not only errors.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt I cannot change that part. It was fixed from my assignment.

Comment: I adapted the title so as not to focus on only part of the problem. Feel free to write your own title, but avoid the trap (which I got caught in) to focus on only part of the solution. Describing in the question what you tried and how exactly that did not help either would make a better question.

Comment: `if( scanf("%99[^\n]", word) == 1) ...`  If you're going to use `scanf`, you must always check its return value, and you must always put a maximum field width on and `%s` or `%[]` conversion specifiers.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you so much. I edit the lower path for what I want to ask.

Comment: @WilliamPursell which part are you talking about? I don't understand. edit:Sorry for my poor english. I mean "part"

Comment: @AchunSirakarun What do you mean by "path"?  I mean that you have some basic errors with your scanf, which is not surprising since it is a terrible function.   As a first step, replace `"%[^\n]"` with `"%99[^\n]"` to avoid a overflowing the buffer.   See http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: I noticed that the description I asked for were already there. Sorry, I missed that. I took the liberty to more explicitly point out a relevant part of that description. If I got it wrong please correct my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your code a bit, I guess this is what you're looking for (the comments in the code explain pretty much all the changes I've made):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char word[100],*ptr,input;
    int count,i,n;
    printf("Enter the word : ");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", word); //changed to %99[^\n] to avoid buffer overflows
    do
    {
        count=0; //count=0 should be here as count++ changes the value of count afterwards
        ptr=word; //ptr=word should be here too since ptr++ changes the value of ptr afterwards
        /* you might have probably gotten a compiler warning because
        of ptr=&word, since &word is char(*)[100] (a pointer to an array of 100 chars)
        and char(*)[100] and char * are quite different,
        so you can either do ptr=word or ptr=&word[0] (both of which point to the first character in the array) */
        //the rest of the code below is basically the same
        printf("Enter the letter : ");
        scanf(" %c", &input);
        if(input == '-'){
                printf("Exit.");
                return 0;
        }
        for(i=0;word[i] != '\0';i++)
        {
            if(*ptr == input)
                count++;
            ptr++;
        }
        printf("Has %d of '%c'",count,input);
        printf("\n");
    }while(input != '-'); //you had missed a ';' here
}
```

The `int main(void)` is because, quoting n1570 (emphasis mine):

> It shall be defined with a return type of int and with no parameters:
> **int main(void) { /* ... */ }** or with two parameters (referred to here
> as argc and argv, though any names may be used, as they are local to
> the function in which they are declared): **int main(int argc, char
> *argv[]) { /* ... */ }** or equivalent

Even though I haven't checked the return value of `scanf()` in the above code, but as mentioned by @Yunnosch in the comment, it's always a good idea to do so.

Comment: I like the `int main` and the subtly different `ptr=word;`. I recommend to also cover them with comments. I'd enjoy seeing a check of scanf return value, or nudging comment there. But you already have my upvote.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks! I added a comment about why I used `ptr=word` in the code.